# comparative advantage

Tags: macroeconomics

a) Suppose that Canada and the US both produce maple syrup and honey. These are the combinations of the two goods that each country can produce in one day:

CANADA  US
Honey in tons       Maple Syrup in tons       Honey in tons         Maple Syrup in tons
0                         60                     0                           50
10                        45                   10                           40
20                       30                    20                           30
30                        15                    30                          20
40  0   40  10
50  0

i)  Who has a comparative advantage in which product?
ii) Suppose that Canada is currently producing 30 tons of honey and 15 tons of maple syrup and the US is currently producing 40 tons of maple syrup and 10 tons of honey. Demonstrate that Canada and the US both benefit from specializing and engaging in trade.
iii)    Illustrate your answer drawing PPFs and showing the combination both countries are able to consume before and after trade

Comment: can you format the data provided correctly? In the given format the quantity combination of the two goods is not clear, making it impossible to answer your question. And try to be more specific with your doubts and show your attempts as well.